# Using split on an input string

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm a beginner to Python 3 and when I try this code it works:

```
a = input('Enter three digits separated by space:')
b = a.split()
mylist = [int(i) for i in b]
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
Enter three digits separated by space:2 3 4
[2, 3, 4]
```

However I get errors when I try this:

```
a = input('Enter three digits separated by space:')
b = a.split()
mylist = [int(i**2) for i in b]
print(mylist)
```

> Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

In fact this works as well:

```
list1 = [2,3,4]
mylist = [int(i**2) for i in list1]
print(mylist)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to do exponentiation *after* converting to an `int`:

```
mylist = [int(i)**2 for i in list1]
```

You can't raise a string to a power (do *you* know what the square of the string "blah" is?), but you can raise a number to a power. So you need to convert the string to a number first.

Of course, `a.split()` returns a list of smaller strings derived from the original string, and you have to turn them into numbers yourself, but you already figured this out.

Comment: It's worth nothing that in the OP's question, the second example works and they are asking about the difference.  The hardcoded `list1` is using integer inputs and that's the main difference compared to the `input` method.  Which takes a string and splits it into a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

Error in your code: you are trying to raise power before converting it to int

```
int(i**2) 
#should be 
int(i)**2
```

Another approach, using **map function**.

> Syntax: map(func, iterable)

In python, String is iterable which means you can iterate over it. For example:

```
for i in "hello":
   print(i)

#output will be: 
    h
    e
    l
    l
    o
```

Another simple concept before moving to map function: split() function will return the list.

```
print(type("hello".split()))
#output will be
<class 'list'>
```

Lets use map function to answer your question:

```
a = map(int, input('Enter three digits separated by space:').split())

mylist = [i**2 for i in a]
print(mylist)
```

Explanation:

- The input() function will ask user to enter three numbers separated by space and that
  will be a string, now you can use split function over the string returned by input().
- Here, split function will return a list.
- Now, map function comes into the picture, it will take each element
  from the list returned at step 2 and map it to the function,     in
  this case, it will map each element of the list to int.
- Variable **a** is map object, and map object is iterable, so you can
  apply for loop or list comprehension(you used list comprehension) to get desired output

Answer (score -1):

you have to give condition for split like " "
suppose the input is 2 3 4 and you want to split it as 2,3,4. and also the input return value as str so you have to change it to int as follows then you can use **

```
 a = input('Enter three digits separated by space:')
 b = map(int,a.split(" "))
 mylist = [i**2 for i in b]
```

this will work for you..

Comment: If you change the OP's code to use this instead this would not solve the problem